# Syphoning out irregularities in a large array using a loop. JS

Tags: javascript

I have this huge array that is representing opening and closing times. (this stretches for an entire week).  I also created a new feature in which it allows users to have holiday hours in which they can change their hours....but also close their doors during a specific day.  The problem that I've run across is when a customer chooses to close for a day, the date for the large array becomes a blank array.

Is there an effective way to trigger something if the elements inside one of those arrays return nothing?

```
[
    [],
    [
        "2015-10-16T13:00:00Z",
        "2015-10-16T21:00:00Z"
    ],
    [],
    [
        "2015-10-18T13:00:00Z",
        "2015-10-18T21:00:00Z"
    ],
    [
        "2015-10-19T05:00:00Z",
        "2015-10-20T05:00:00Z"
    ],
    [
        "2015-10-20T13:00:00Z",
        "2015-10-20T21:00:00Z"
    ],
    [
        "2015-10-21T13:00:00Z",
        "2015-10-21T21:00:00Z"
    ]
]
```

So up here ^^ is what my large array looks like when a customer chooses to be closed for the day.

Comment: google for "mdn filter" and use that on your array before processing it.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger something"? If you are processing the whole array in a loop you can do a test whether the current element has `.length === 0` and then do something. If you want to remove those empty elements you can use `.filter()` as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` and check for `x.length === 0` condition.

```js
(function() {
  var data = [
    [],
    [
      "2015-10-16T13:00:00Z",
      "2015-10-16T21:00:00Z"
    ],
    [],
    [
      "2015-10-18T13:00:00Z",
      "2015-10-18T21:00:00Z"
    ],
    [
      "2015-10-19T05:00:00Z",
      "2015-10-20T05:00:00Z"
    ],
    [
      "2015-10-20T13:00:00Z",
      "2015-10-20T21:00:00Z"
    ],
    [
      "2015-10-21T13:00:00Z",
      "2015-10-21T21:00:00Z"
    ]
  ];

  data.map(function(x, y) {
    if (x.length === 0) {
      console.log("There is no data in the position: " + y + ".");
    }
  });
})();
```